# How to get zend framework skeleton old versions like 2.3

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-framework2, skeleton-code

how do I installed zend framework 2. 
how do i download skeleton 2.3.0, Each and Every time I try I got latest version of skeleton application.

how to install zend framework 2.3.0  in xampp localhost

I have download frash copy of Archives
from http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives

Extract archive 2.3.0 rename it and paste folder at htdocs as zf2

and run below command in cmd

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\composer require zendframework/zendframework 2.3
```

its showing Error as below [image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from archives or using composer.

**Archives**

http://framework.zend.com/downloads/archives

**Composer**

```
$ composer require zendframework/zendframework 2.3
```

your composer.json should look like below after you run above command

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3"
    }
}
```

Or you can directly edit composer.json and run

```
$ composer update
```

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework>composer require zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0    I user above command in my project folder its give me error  please have a look. Problem 1
    - The requested package zendframework/zendframework No version set (parsed a
s 1.0.0) could not be found.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for ircmaxell/random-lib dev-master -> satisfiable by
 ircmaxell/random-lib[dev-master].
    - ircmaxell/random-lib dev-master requires ircmaxell/security-lib 1.1.*@dev
-> no matching package found.

Comment: Did you type it correct? there is a space and version number after zendframework/zendframework. Also you can edit composer.json and add "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3" to "require" section

Comment: After you edit composer.json did you run composer update

Comment: Can you edit your question and include composer.json and the error screen?

Comment: ques edited as per your instruction.. please have a look.  I did dame in maching change in composer.json file too.

Comment: You typed zendframework/zendfrawork instead of zendframework/zendframework

Comment: that screen shot mistakely i have type.. but I have type correctly too. still same error... please see edited que.. i have update screenshot

Comment: Can you edit your question ans show composer.json file. Also can you try $ composer require zendframework/zendframework 2.3.0 instead of 2.3

Comment: I have updated require  files as..   "require": {  
        "php": ">=5.3.23",
   "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.0",
        "zendframework/zendxml": "~1.0-dev"
    }  as you said... and run cmd, composer update  still same errors as showing in screenshot

Comment: Does your composer.json has "minimum-stability": "dev"

Comment: no its not have anything like "minimum-stability":"dev"

Comment: today I have download fresh copy of zend framework 2.3.0 and trying to run above cmd.. still not working.. change composer.json file too.

Comment: Add "minimum-stability":"dev" to composer.json and see

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: connect me if in skype after 8pm today.. nitesh.pawar4 I will wait.

Comment: Read the ZF2 documentation instead